# I did not get the env.test.properties file in the maven project hierarchy

Tags: java, maven

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.1: run (default) on
>   project clean: Error executing ant tasks: Warning: Could not fi nd
>   file
>   C:\Users\satyam\IdeaProjects\Demo\src\main\resources\env.test.properties
>   to copy. -> [Help 1]

```
enter code here

 <profile>
 <id>test</id>
 <build>
 <plugins>
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <echo>Using env.test.properties</echo>
                    <copy file="src/main/resources/env.test.properties"
                 tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/env.properties"/>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
       </execution>
       </executions>
       </plugin>
       </plugins>
       </build>
        </profile>
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the relevant part of the POM.

Comment: Do you have a file at the location `C:\Users\satyam\IdeaProjects\Demo\src\main\resources\env.test.properties`?

Comment: no, i am unable to find the file env.test.properties in the hirearchy of the project. how i locate it plz tell me - Alexander